# How to determine an integral of a differential form?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, parametrization

Let 
$$ \eta = x^2 \, dy \wedge dz + yx\,dz \wedge dx + z^3 \, dx \wedge dy $$

Can you show me how to calculate :

$$   \int_{\Phi} \eta, $$
where $ \Phi $ is supposed to be the parametrization of the unitsphere in $\mathbb{R}^3? $

Any help very appreciated !!

Comment: write $\Phi = g([0,2\pi)\times[0,\pi)$), $(x,y,z) = g(\theta,\phi)$, where $g$ defines spherical coordinates, then $\int_{g([0,2\pi)\times[0,\pi))} \eta = \int_{[0,2\pi)\times[0,\pi)} g^* \eta $, this should get you to a classical iterated integral

Comment: is $g* \eta $ the convolution? sorry, differential forms are new to me

Comment: no, it is the pullback

Comment: do you mind showing me exactly?

Comment: you can see the definition and an example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399032/pullback-calculation

Comment: okay, but is there another way? Because I don't think we have defined it

Comment: What do you have then?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What specifically are you having trouble with. If it’s an exercise that’s part of a course you’re taking, I’d expect that a general method for computing such integrals has already been covered in the material. Are you perhaps having trouble coming up with a suitable parameterization?

Comment: You might find my [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) helpful. See the latter half of MATH 3510.